# Where to implement a Linked List Stack in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement a Linked List Stack in my Rails app which is a basic to-do list.  But I am not sure where I would place the code for the Linked List within the current Rails App structure. Can someone offer any guidance?  Would this go within the Model or the Controller?

**Screenshot of Basic to do list app**
[image: Todolist]

**Tasks Controller:**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

 def create
   @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

   if @task.save
     flash[:notice] = "Task created successfully"
   else
     flash[:error] = "Error creating task"
   end

   redirect_to current_user
 end

 def destroy
  @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])

  if @task.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Task completed successfully"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error completing task"
  end

  redirect_to current_user
end

private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:name)
end
```

**Show.html.erb file for the tasks created**

```
 <h1>Hello, <%= current_user.email %></h1>

 <h2>Create New Task</h2>
 <%= form_for [current_user, @task] do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 <% end %>
 <h2>Current Tasks</h2>
 <% current_user.tasks.each do | task| %>
   <p>
     <%= task.name %>
     <%=link_to [current_user, task], method: :delete do %>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
     <% end %>
   </p>
 <% end %>
```

**Task.rb(Model)**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User.rb(Model)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :tasks
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**The Linkedlist Stack I would like to implement in the Rails App**

```
module LinkedList
  class Node
    attr_accessor :value, :next_node

    def initialize(value, next_node)
      @value = value
      @next_node = next_node
      end
    end

    class Stack
      def initialize
        @first = nil
      end

      def push(value)
        @first = Node.new(value, @first)
      end

      def pop
        flash[:notice] = "Task completed successfully" if is_empty?
        value = @first.value
        @first = @first.next_node
        value
      end

      def is_empty?
        @first.nil?
      end
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Any non-web application code (i.e. something that could be a standalone Ruby object) goes in the `/lib` folder.

First include the `lib` folder to your Rails application.

This is not done by default so people can have the flexibility of explicitly `require`-ing parts of library when necessary.

We're going to include all of `lib` by doing the following:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Then inside of `lib`, let's create a `linked_list.rb` file.

Here you can write code and it will be should be included within your application, due to autoload loading every first level file in `lib`.

For more complex libraries, let's call it `test`, you will need to do the following:

1. Make a folder and a Ruby file called `test`.
2. In the file, require all the classes from the folder.

For example:

```
# /lib/test/class1.rb
module Test
  class Class1
  end
end
```

Assuming we also have `Class2` and `Class3`.

```
# /lib/test.rb
module Test
end

require 'test/class1'
require 'test/class2'
require 'test/class3'
```